# Can lips become bigger

Tags: plastic-surgery

Could lips become bigger with physic way?I see many people around me that have a small lips but they managed to do it bigger, is this normal?its a healthy issue or they did a surgery?I don't think someone can make lips bigger with physic way.How can someone do this if you could share your opinion.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lip_plate